# Accumulation functions and investments

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

Suppose we invest $\$50$ at time 0.5 and $\$200$ at time 1.5; the accumulation function that applies on the interval $[0,1]$ is $a(t) = 1+t^2$, and simple interest with $i = 5%$ applies on the interval $[1,2]$. Find the total accumulated value of the investments at time 2.

My attempt:

I know that I need to discount $\$50$ with the first accumulation function at time $0$, that is:
$$\frac{50}{1+(0.5)^2}$$

Then I accumulate it at time 1:
$$\frac{50*(1+1^2)}{1+(0.5)^2}$$

My problem starts when i want to accumulate it with simple interest on the interval $[1,2]$: Do I just multiply it by: $1+0.05*1$ to have an accumulated value of the first investment at time 2 equals to:

$$\frac{50*(1+1^2)*(1+0.05*1)}{1+(0.5)^2}$$

Or is this approach wrong?

Also How do I accumulate the second investment?

Any hints or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the very first step.  The $50$ is accumulating.  Why would you discount it?  You need to be using $a(t)

Comment: Yes, this is the right approach-imho.